# OpenCV VideoWriter Size and FourCC issue

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using **VideoWriter** to record frames. These frames are of **Mat** type.
Currently, I am able to store video by using following:

```
<c++>VideoWriter writer("Video.avi", **-1**,60, Size(imgw, imgh),false);  </c++>
```

Just manually select the type of video. Usually I use RLE. Program sometimes crush with other types.

But, if I use following, the video size is zero.

```
<c>VideoWriter writer("Video.avi", **fourcc('P','I','M','1')**,60, Size(imgw, imgh),false);  </c>
```

or

```
**fourcc('A','A','S','C')**
```

Is there something wrong? 
I count 600 frames, then release writer.

Comment: Do you have the codecs installed?

Comment: i think so. because i could manually selecting video type while program running. just failed to select type in code.